# What does this translate to?

Tags: translation

I was wondering if someone could help me translate this.  Apologies for it being sideways - not the best at tech.  Thank you very much for your time, and I hope you have a great day.

[image]

Comment: 不见不散  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%8B%E4%B8%8D%E6%95%A3#Chinese) && [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E4%B8%8D%E8%A7%81%E4%B8%8D%E6%95%A3)

Answer (score 2):

1. If “不见不散” is used between individuals, the meaning is
   "See you there" or "See you then". Used as a concluding remark after making an appointment with other people.
2. It is also common on posters and trailers, which means "We'll be there". For example: 'This show will be on air at 20:00 pm tomorrow, we 不见不散'

The 4 chanracters "不" "见" "不" "散" in english are "not" "see" "not" "depart". Direct translation is more like "Not leaving without seeing you"